# Why does the program start anew when I click button2?

Tags: c#, winforms

Every time I click the No button (here button2_click), the program opens itself again, and I cannot figure out why.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process game = new Process();

    game.StartInfo.FileName = "ShovelShovel.exe";
    game.Start();
}
```

I figured it would launch the game and close, but if I click the button, it just launches my program again. If I click No on that form, then I get a huge list of unhandled exceptions.

Whether I do this.Close(); or Application.Exit(); the program still opens itself.

Can anyone tell me why it would open again? I haven't altered Program.cs in anyway.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your "No" button (here, button2) launches a "ShovelShovel.exe" process in the click event.. that is why it is opening itself again..

Comment: Why would the launcher program close? You're certainly not exiting the launcher anywhere in the code you've shown us. And obviously, if you click `button2` twice, then `button2_Click()` will get called twice.

Comment: The program shown above is called "ShovelShovel Settings.exe" I only click the button once, and it opens another window. It should be opening the EXE, not opening itself.

Comment: Whether I do this.Close(); or Application.Exit(); the program still opens itself.

Comment: Does no one actually want to be helpful? I didn't do anything, and already I have a -3 rating for this question...

Comment: Where are you doing `this.Close()` or `Application.Exit()`? It depends on whether those lines are being executed or not. Try debugging the code to see if those lines are ever executed.

Comment: I'm doing them after game.Start(); I put a breakpoint on it, and the window opens before the line is ran, so it never runs. I don't know why this is.

Comment: @Fiona: It is not that we dont want to be helpful, downvotes simply mean we think it is a bad question for various reasons. Lack of information, lack of effort on your part, lack of prior research, etc. You could have found the correct way to do this with minimal googling.

Comment: @caesay I've been Googling for hours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (assuming that the program you are working from is "ShovelShovel Settings.exe" and is the launcher for "ShovelShovel.exe")

```
//launch game
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "ShovelShovel.exe";
Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);

//close
this.Close();
```

Or even just

```
Process.Start("ShovelShovel.exe");
```

If this is still starting the same application, you either have the wrong path, or the exe's are the same.

To double check, why dont you go into the directory and execute "ShovelShovel.exe" manually from WindowsExplorer.

Comment: OP is not using the static Start() method

Comment: So? I dont see how that is relavant. The Op wants to know how to start a process.

Comment: Then are you sure that "ShovelShovel.exe" is in fact the correct path?

Comment: Yes, it's in the same directory as the Settings executable. There is no error/warning that the file can't be found.

Comment: Double check with the method i described in the answer

Comment: LOL. We've all been there, bro. Every line of code we right has the potential to have a bug. It's not an easy profession, which is too bad because it's often trivialized by others. Keep your head up.